# Github GraphQL list repo permissions for a Team

Tags: github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

I am really struggling to get anything sensible out of the GitHub GraphQL api...
I want to get a list of repos and the permission levels for a team.  So far I have

```
Q= """query {
  organization(login: "MY_ORG") {
      team(slug:"MY_TEAM") {
          name
          repositories(first:3){
              nodes {
                  name
              }
              edges {
                  permission
              }
          }
      }
  }
}"""
```

which returns

```
{'data': {'organization': {'team': {'name': 'MY_TEAM',
'repositories': {'nodes': [{'name': 'REPO1'},
  {'name': 'REPO2'},
  {'name': 'REPO3'}],
 'edges': [{'permission': 'ADMIN'},
  {'permission': 'ADMIN'},
  {'permission': 'ADMIN'}]}}}}}
```

But I cannot see any way to list the permission and the repo name together as there is no way to go from a teamrepositoryedge to a repository node or vice versa :/

I feel I am missing something obvious and just not seeing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually found that there is a node in the edge it just isn't documented like others are :(

```
query {
organization(login: "MY_ORG") {
    team(slug:"MY_TEAM"){
        name
        repositories(first:3){
            edges {
                permission
                node {
                    name
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

{'data': {'organization': {'team': {'name': 'MY_TEAM',
'repositories': {'edges': [{'permission': 'ADMIN',
   'node': {'name': 'REPO1'}},
  {'permission': 'ADMIN', 'node': {'name': 'REPO2'}},
  {'permission': 'ADMIN', 'node': {'name': 'REPO3'}}]}}}}}
```